# Trying to replace punctuation with re.sub but getting error

Tags: python, python-re

I've had success with re.sub on another project but not on this one and I can't tell why. It keeps coming up with this error and I'm not sure what it exactly means.

Here's the code I'm having trouble with:

```
import re
def a(sentence):
  sentence=sentence.lower()
  sentence=sentence.split()
  sentence = re.sub(r'[!@#$%&*?]','',sentence)
  print(sentence)
  return
```

---And the error I'm getting:

```
def sub(pattern, repl, string, count=0, flags=0):
"""Return the string obtained by replacing the leftmost
non-overlapping occurrences of the pattern in string by the
replacement repl.  repl can be either a string or a callable;
if a string, backslash escapes in it are processed.  If it is
a callable, it's passed the Match object and must return
a replacement string to be used."""
return _compile(pattern, flags).sub(repl, string, count)
```

Answer (score 0):

`sentence.split()` creates a list and `re.sub()` is expecting a string.  Why split it?

Comment: The project required individual words (list) for data analysis later. Didn't cross my mind about .split made a list re.sub required a string. Switched .split and re.sub() around and it works now. Thank you